# Mongo sync: slow down or stop sync?

Tags: mongodb

All,

I have a replicaset setup where I run two mongo processes, M_pri on port 28001 and M_sec on 28002 in the same machine with the following config:

```
    "_id" : "myReplSet",
    "version" : 1,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "localhost:28001",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : false,
                    "priority" : 1,
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "localhost:28002",
                    "arbiterOnly" : false,
                    "buildIndexes" : true,
                    "hidden" : true,
                    "priority" : 0,
                    "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                    "votes" : 1
            }
    ],
    "settings" : {
            "chainingAllowed" : true,
            "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
            "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
            "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
            "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : 2000,
            "getLastErrorModes" : {

            },
            "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("593565b0ebd8ca36a07c6576")
    }
```

The intention for this setup is to take a daily mongodump (gunzip) off M_sec. During the mongodump the whole of my system slow down as I have these processes that make writes and reads off the M_pri.

Is there a way by which I could stop the sync from Primary to Secondary mongo during the time when I am doing a mongodump off M_sec?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the M_sec to be a delayed member (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/#replica-set-delayed-members), so it will replicate from M_pri with a delay.
Things to keep in mind:

> Requirements
>
> Delayed members:
>
> - Must be priority 0 members. Set the priority to 0 to prevent a delayed member from becoming primary.
> - Should be hidden members. Always prevent applications from seeing and
>     querying delayed members.
>     do vote in elections for primary, if members[n].votes is set to 1.
>
> Behavior
>
> Delayed members copy and apply operations from the source oplog on a
>   delay. When choosing the amount of delay, consider that the amount of
>   delay:
>
> - must be equal to or greater than your expected maintenance window durations.
> - must be smaller than the capacity of the oplog. For more information on oplog size, see Oplog Size.

Configuration example:

```
    {
   "_id" : <num>,
   "host" : <hostname:port>,
   "priority" : 0,
   "slaveDelay" : <seconds>,
   "hidden" : true
}
```